# how to change a Windows phone 7 market place application icon

Tags: windows-phone-7

I uploaded windows phone 7 app in market and it's rejected by apphub market,with reason of displaying default app icon,here the application icon is not being displayed instead it shows an default application icon.I also uploaded all design images in artwork design with suitable dimension of icon.Please help me to show application icon in market place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking in the app hub at the details of your released ap, this always shows the default "cog" app at the top.
If you've uploaded the correcct images these will be seen in the application artwork section of the page.

If the wrong images are being displayed in the marketplace, is this the phone marketplace or the desktop one? Or both?

If the images displayed in the marketplace don't match the ones listed in the details in the app hub then you should contact app hub support.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at [the end of this post](http://blogs.infosupport.com/blogs/ernow/archive/2011/06/02/windows-phone-7-drawing-graphics-for-your-application-with-inkscape-part-ii-icons.aspx)

It shows how to set these icons. (The posts starts with drawing them but you could skip that)

[image]